# "Points" system for CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm building a custom social networking package using CakePHP. We'd like to have a system where users earn points based on events. Upload a photo? 10 points for you. Comment on one? 5 points. etc. These points can be cached in to do stuff such as get premium access to some content that users might need to pay cash for otherwise.

In addition, I'd like for a message to show up, separately from the Session Flash message. I'd also like for the site admins to be able to configure points and messages based on events. This way they can do promos for stuff like visiting/logging in, or photo posting during a weekend/week and then just put the number back when it promo is done.

Is there a Component or Behavior out there that can help me with this? If not, is there a basic idea I could go with to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a Cake can handle this fine without a plugin. I think you would need to attach the points to each individual item that a user submits (e.g. photos, comments, etc.). So, in each Model, I would add in a point value column.

For the admin side, it's a little harder, because the best way to link everything would be User HABTM Photo, Comment, Etc. That means to adjust/edit points you would have to load a user first. This would work, unless your expecting thousands of users. Then, it might get overwhelming, although it would still be functional.

A global points on/off switch, or one targeting a specific model like photos, can be handled in another model, say Point. Here you could set two columns resource and points. So, for example, Photos, 10; Comments, 5... An off switch could set one or more of these to 0. This is all covered really well in the Saving Your Data page on the CakePHP docs (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html). Again, hope this helps.

Comment: Although developing these behaviors as a plugin is not *nescessary*, it may be an option to do so in case you'd like to reuse the points system for other websites as well. Plugins cause no serious overhead in a CakePHP website, so don't let this withold you from using/creating them